# What do you call the construction noun + "-ed" which, like an adjective, can modify another noun?

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives, terminology, suffixes

There are some words that appear to be adjectives formed from nouns inflected with something that looks like the past participle ending "-ed".  Some of these are preceded (hyphenated in my usage) with a color or number.  Some examples, with head nouns that they can modify, are: two-headed snake, red-haired woman, three-masted schooner, dimpled cheek, pimpled face, frilled shirt and porticoed entrance.  What is the name for this noun-plus-past-participle-ending construction, if it has a name?

Comment: These are _compound adjectives._ _dimpled_, _frilled_, _porticoed_ are simply _adjectives_ formed from verbs.

Comment: Subset compound participial adjectives.

Comment: Thank you, @Edwin Ashworth!  MUCH appreciated.  Didn't know how to use a dictionary / grammar manual to find a word when all I knew was the meaning / characteristics.

Comment: Hair? Portico? These are of course not exclusively formed from verbs at all, in response to user405662. And what about examples that aren't compound, such as pimpled face or wooded valley @EdwinAshworth?

Comment: These are compound adjectives, subset compound participial adjectives. The simplex examples, _dimpled, frilled, porticoed_ are usually simply 'participial adjectives' ... adjectives formed from verbs, but in some cases modelled on these without there being a pre-existing verb ('pseudo-participial adjectives', eg 'talented').  And, @oxwilder,  already covered ELU.